# eigenvalues of two nonnegative matrices

Tags: eigenvalues, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric non-negative matrices. If $A\geq B$ (i.e., $A-B$ is a nonnegative matrix), can we say that $\lambda_i(A) \geq \lambda_i(B)$ for all $i$, where $\lambda_i$ denotes the i--th largest eigenvalue

(I know it holds for the largest eigenvalue but I am interested in the second largest one). If it does not always hold, what condition on it makes my statement true.

Comment: trivial application of minmax formulae.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$ and  $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.  Or did you mean positive semidefinite instead of nonnegative?

Comment: Thanks, your counterexample disproves my statement. Now I am looking for a condition that makes my statement true.